# async foreach inside async series nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-async

I'm working on **node async library**. I'm not able to execute in the **sequence** i want. i don't know where I'm going wrong
here is the code.. in comments i have defined order number..
currently its executing in **2,3,4,5,1** order i want in **1,2,3,4,5** order ....kindly help

```
function getAsExhibitors(req, res) {
    //getting all exhibitors against an event
    var exhibitors = [];
    var eac_app_names = [];
    async.series([function(callback){
        models.EacExhibitorsExt.find({ deleted: false,userid: req.user._id}).sort({ modified: -1 }).exec(function(err, myExhibitors) {
            exhibitors = myExhibitors;
            callback();
        });
    },function(callback){
        async.forEach(exhibitors,function(exhibitor,callback){
            models.Eac.findById(exhibitor.eventid).exec(function(err,eac){
                eac_app_names[exhibitors.indexOf(exhibitor)]=eac;
                console.log("-----------------1--------------"+eac_app_names);
            });
            console.log("-----------------2--------------"+eac_app_names);
            callback();
        },function(err) {
            console.log("-----------------3--------------"+eac_app_names);
            callback();
        });
    }],function(err) { //This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return next(err);
        //Here locals will be populated with 'exhibitors' and 'apps'
        console.log("-------------------------4------"+eac_app_names);
        console.log("-------------------------5------"+eac_app_names.name);
        res.locals.exhibitors = exhibitors; 
        res.locals.eac_app_names = eac_app_names;   
        res.render('eac/eac_reg_as_exhibitor', { title: "My Event Exhibitors", asexhibitor: exhibitors,app_names:eac_app_names});
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All mongoose methods work as asynchronous.In your scenario try this way:

```
function getAsExhibitors(req, res) {
    //getting all exhibitors against an event
    var exhibitors = [];
    var eac_app_names = [];
    async.series([function(callback){
        models.EacExhibitorsExt.find({ deleted: false,userid: req.user._id}).sort({ modified: -1 }).exec(function(err, myExhibitors) {
            exhibitors = myExhibitors;
            callback();
        });
    },function(callback){
        async.forEach(exhibitors,function(exhibitor,callback){
            models.Eac.findById(exhibitor.eventid).exec(function(err,eac){
                eac_app_names[exhibitors.indexOf(exhibitor)]=eac;
                console.log("-----------------1--------------"+eac_app_names);
 console.log("-----------------2--------------"+eac_app_names);
            callback();
            });

        },function(err) {
            console.log("-----------------3--------------"+eac_app_names);
            callback();
        });
    }],function(err) { //This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return next(err);
        //Here locals will be populated with 'exhibitors' and 'apps'
        console.log("-------------------------4------"+eac_app_names);
        console.log("-------------------------5------"+eac_app_names.name);
        res.locals.exhibitors = exhibitors; 
        res.locals.eac_app_names = eac_app_names;   
        res.render('eac/eac_reg_as_exhibitor', { title: "My Event Exhibitors", asexhibitor: exhibitors,app_names:eac_app_names});
    }); 
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You are welcome to use es6 with generator.
Try out [co-foreach-series](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-foreach-series) to get each of the array element and execute async function one by one.

#### ForEach Series Example

```
foreach(yourArray, function(element, index) {
// Each of this function will be executed one after one
co(function*() {
   // Do some async task, and wait until this task be finished
   yield yourAsyncFunc(); 
   yield doOtherAsyncTasks();
})
```

})